# Unable to attach debugger in Android Studio in MacBook

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-debug

I am unable to attach debugger in Android Studio in MacBook. I am getting this error

```
Failed to start monitoring <deviceID>
```

I have tried multiple solutions :

1. Turn on/off usb debugging on device
2. Invalidate cache/restart Android Studio & Build -> Clean project
3. Stop and start adb server from terminal
4. Changing cable/usb port
5. Reboot Android device, Mac
6. Reset Android device
7. Upgrade gradle plugin & Android Studio to new version

Setup:
Macbook,
Android Studio 4.2,
Pixel 3a Android 11

OnDevice USB Preferences:

- USB Controlled by: This Device
- Use USB For: No Data transfer

I was able to work with the debugger fine for a very long time (~8 months) but it stopped abruptly few days ago and did not have any luck since then.

I have tried various solutions from stackoverflow, medium most of them fall under the things I have tried above and I have observed that the solutions are for Windows machines, so wondering if there is anything different for Android Studio on Macbook?

Appreciate your time looking into this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: any solution you found? i'm facing same here

Comment: Once I click on the attach debugger, a window open up. In the for the option "Use Android debug settings from" I choose my app from the dropdown. Try to see if that works

Comment: it works for me but after choose my device it fails to be attached see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71034385/operation-not-permitted-while-attaching-debugger